# Excel VBA to make a sequence of cells equal to a value. Convert annual dummy into quarterly

Tags: vba, excel

How can I write a function or macro in order to convert annual dummy variable into quarterly?
Specifically I want:
Suppose in cell A1 I have value 0, I want B(1:4) 0. Then A2 = 0, I want B(5:8) 0. Then A3 =1 B(8:11) =1 and so on for 5000 Cells in A column.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try with this.

```
Public Sub fillCell()

    Dim row, bRow, startRow, endRow As Integer

    startRow = 1
    endRow = 4

    With Sheets("sheetname")

        'Looping from 1 to 5000, increase by 1
        For row = 1 To 5000 Step 1

                For bRow = startRow To endRow

                    .Range("B" & bRow) = .Range("A" & row)

                Next bRow

                startRow = startRow + 4
                endRow = endRow + 4

       Next row

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn`t take care of 1 in data and sequence is not correct either. I tried it on 0
1
1
1
0
0
 in column A and got 12 zeros in B

Comment: Sorry, I miss. I modified my code. Please try that new one.

Comment: So glad..! If it is sure, mark as answer and upvote.

Comment: I will do it immediately after I get enough rating. I just recently registered...

Comment: No, you can accept answer whatever your rating. I said to accept my answer. Just click mark beside answer. Thats all.